# Regular expression to get the letters with numbers on the left

Tags: regex

I want to extract the letters with numbers on the left.

For example `3F 4G XY` output `F` and `G`.

I tried to do this using this regular expression `(?=\d)[A-Z]`, but failed.

Look at the following code:

```js
s = "1A 2B 3C IJK  X1 Y2 Z3"
s.match(/(?=\d)[A-Z]/g)  // null

s.match(/[A-Z](?=\d)/g)  // [ 'X', 'Y', 'Z' ]
```

I was surprised why the first match was not found, and the second was found correctly.

In my opinion, this even expression is the same, but the left and right change.

Did I get it wrong?

That,

How do I get this output `['A', 'B', 'C']`?

Comment: It should be a positive lookbehind `(?<=\d)[A-Z]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the text is processed from left to right the number is processed first, so you need a look-behind:

```
(?<=\d)[A-Z]
```

So the regex engine steps behind into the already processed text to look for your pattern